# Using isset() method to vaidate login form. PHP

Tags: php, html

I was trying to create this login form to validate on the same page. it should hide the form once the login is validated. I have been testing is, but its not showing any error.
When i click on the submit button, it just refreshes the page.

```
    <table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td><?php
    $DisplayForm = TRUE;
    $errors = 0;

    if(isset($_POST['loginForm'])){
    include("dbconnect.php");
    if($DBConnect !== FALSE){
    $SQLstring = "SELECT userid, first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE username ='".
    $_POST['uname']. "' and password = '".md5($_POST['pass'])."'";
    $DisplayForm = FALSE;
    $QueryResult = @mysql_query($SQLstring, $DBConnect);
    echo mysql_error();
    if (mysql_num_rows($QueryResult)=== 0){
      echo "<p>The email address/password " . 
      " combination is not valid.</p>\n";
      ++$errors;
      $DisplayForm = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
      $DisplayForm = FALSE;
    }

    }

    } 

    if ($DisplayForm)
    {?>


     <form id="form1" name="loginForm" method="post" action="index.php">
    <table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="93" bgcolor="#DACFAF"><strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Username:</strong></td>
      <td width="149" bgcolor="#DACFAF"><label for="textfield"></label>
      <input type="text" name="uname" id="textfield" /></td>
      <td width="76" bgcolor="#DACFAF"><strong>Password:</strong></td>
      <td width="150" bgcolor="#DACFAF"><label for="textfield2"></label>
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /></td>
      <td width="196" bgcolor="#DACFAF"><input type="image" name="login" src="images/login.jpg" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="68" bgcolor="#DACFAF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="68" bgcolor="#DACFAF"><strong><a href="register.php">Register</a></strong>    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
    </form>

    <?php }
    else {
        $Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);
      $userID = $Row['userid'];
      $userName = $Row['first_name']. " ". $Row['last_name'];
      echo "<p>Welcome back, $userName!</p>\n";
      }


     ?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: 1. You're open to SQL injection. 2. Stop using the `mysql_` functions - they've been depcrecated for years. 3. Don't use `md5()` for passwords - it's been broken for years.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a submit button.

Add the following to your form :

```
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" />
```

Then you can check in your first isset-line: `isset($_POST['uname'] && $_POST['pass']);`

Answer (score 0):

You could not apply isset on `<form>`. Try to apply isset on input field

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['uname'] && isset($_POST['pass'])) {

// .. foo

}

?>
```

Moreover, your form is never submitted. Add `<input type="submit" value="Register" />`

Answer (score -1):

To check if something's been posted, you should instead add a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="wasSubmitted" value="true">
```

Then check `isset($_POST['wasSubmitted'])`, or `$_POST['submitted'] == 'true'`.

Only fields are contained in the `$_POST[]` superglobal.

Comment: Thanks guys, its working now. The ... if(isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) worked.